# How to bind database table column name values to windows form combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm trying to bind column name values into the combobox but I'm getting an error. What I'm doing wrong?

I'm getting error on this line `"string sName = MyReader.GetString("Part#");"`

```
Error message: 
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetString(int)' has some invalid arguments

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'
```

.

```
    void FillComboBox()
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblInventory", con);
        SqlDataReader MyReader;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            MyReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (MyReader.Read())
            {
                string sName = MyReader.GetString("Part#");
                comboBox2.Items.Add(sName);
            }



        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Read the error message!

Comment: I've read it, the column Part# is in string format. How come it is showing cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'?

Comment: This is a compiler error, not runtime and unrelated to your column format. Simple, the compiler is telling you that you have a bug and giving you enough information in the messages. Hint -  GetString(**int**)

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation of GetString:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It is never good to use select * in code. Think what happens if the DBA adds a new column to the table - the code gets more than it was designed for. Specify the columns you need:

```
select Part# from tblInventory
string sName = MyReader.GetString(0);
```

gets the first column from the select.